# pass json object to controller action with get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, get

I am working with asp.net mvc4. I have an action method which is a get method as it returns a an mvc view that is called from JavaScript/Jquery.

The javascript makes a get request to the controller action. I have a json object that I would like to pass to the mvc action. But as its a get request, as I need to return a view from it, it is posing difficult.

Is it possible to pass a json object that maps to an object on the signature of the controller action? I was looking libraries that may help such as http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Cant you pass values as URL parameters? However, you will have to make sure the JSON string gets encoded using the JS function `encodeURIComponent`. Additionnaly, the URI has a maximum length that could prevent you from using this approach.

Please note that the GET method should not be used for actions that might have side-effects such as creating or modifying resources.

Comment: why does it need to be a get? (everything about this screams post)

Comment: So if I want to retrieve an mvc view from an action based on passed in values and render the content of the view in markup. Is a POST the best way to do this? How is performance wise when compared to GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need any external APIs to do that. All you need to do is make an c# object with the same property and name as the JSON Object.
For E.g. Create an Object as

```
public class MyObject{
    public string MyProperty1{get; set;}
    public string Property2{get; set;}
}
```

And creating object in the jquery is all correct i assume and use jquery syntax like
as below

```
$.get('@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")',
    {myObject: jqueryObject},
    function(resp){$("#myDiv").innerHTML(resp);});
```

And in case of Action use function declaration like

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyObject myObject)
{
    // your code here
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView", myModelForPartialView);
}
```

BTW this way works for both Get and Post.

Comment: You may want to add [fromBody] as an attribute to the method parameter. public ActionResult MyAction([FromBody]MyObject myObject)

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like servicestack http://www.servicestack.net/   this takes care of everything, and does it very well,   as an alternative there is the MVC API options, but servicestack is better at this.

I am sure if you look at this project, you will either get great ideas from it, or learn to decouple your data driven code, away from your UI project.